# Why does my "EventListener" Function only executes once?

Tags: javascript

Why does this only run once and not every time my mouse moves?

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) { 

   let x = e.clientX; 
   let y = e.clientY; 

       if(x > 1500){
        document.write("A");
         }
        if(x < 1500) {
        document.write("C");
         }

   });
```

Comment: `document.write` should never be used, and if you learned it from some resource that resource might be outdated. Anyway, replace it with `console.log` (and open your console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write()` shouldn't be used for something like this as it will throw out the old document in favor of a new one, which is most-likely why it appears that the event handler is only triggering once. Instead, you should be updating the contents of a pre-existing DOM element.

And, it would be more appropriate to set the handler up on the `document`, rather than the `window`.

Also, you shouldn't have two separate `if` statements, you can just add an `else` to the first one.

And, try using a smaller value than 1500, otherwise you won't see any change unless you go over that amount.

```js
let output = document.querySelector("div");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) { 

   let x = e.clientX; 
   let y = e.clientY; 
   console.log("x coord: " + x, "y coord: " + y);

   if(x > 300){
    // Write your output into an existing DOM element
    output.textContent = "Above 300";
   } else {
    output.textContent = "Below 300";
   }
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```